# Encrypt linux with luks and resize partitions

Tags: linux, boot

This tutorial works great https://www.linux.com/blog/how-full-encrypt-your-linux-system-lvm-luks, I can assign any size for root, home and swap
but I would like to keep the boot partition on the same drive. 
I am using linux mint, the installation has the option to do it automatically but it does not allow me to choose the size for the partitions. 
I don't want to encrypt just the home parittion (as well offered on the installation).
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you follow that guide you end up with a fully encrypted disc. In that case your `boot` partition will eventually also be encrypted. This is not supported by many bootloaders. Actually I could only find [some patches for `GRUB`](http://grub.johnlane.ie) and I'm not sure if they will work with EFI. The more common case is to have boot unencrypted and have a partitioning scheme like `sda1=boot` and `sda2=lvm`. The Arch Linux Wiki has a great article on disc encryption explaining different variants with their respective features and drawbacks. You should check it out.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Disk_encryption